# edmx import tables in tables with first letter uppercase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edmx

Hi i am using database first, database is in Mysql.

i import the data using edmx designer database first, however, it imported with the first letter in lowercase, so do the generated classes.

How can change it to make it uppercase ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the first letter of an entity to upper or lower while generating edmx. But you can change the name from singular to plural and vice versa.